# How can I fix main section on homepage website? Link will be attached

Tags: html, css

I am working on portfolio site.  I want to figure out why my main section on my homepage is extended so far down but on the other pages it stops right below content.  Here is the code.

**CSS for all pages:**

```
body {
    background-color:#A6FFFF;
    width:100%;
}
#header, #main, #footer {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#header, #footer {
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
}
#header {
    margin-bottom:2px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
#footer {
    margin-top:2px;
    text-align:right;
    border:2px;
}
#main {
    position:relative;
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:center;
}
#nav {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
#nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**Homepage HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="auto-style1">
    <div id="header">Header
        <h1>Creative Minds Inc.</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">Navigation
        <ul>
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="tipsandtricks.html">Tips and Tricks</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="getintouch.html">Get in Touch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">Main
        <h2>A passion for design and a creative mind.</h2>
        <h3>Design, Develop, Dream</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer
        <h3>Creative Minds Inc.  Jon Mo</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Other pages HTML:**

```
<body>
<body>
<div id="header">Header
    <h1>Creative Minds Inc.</h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">Navigation
    <ul>
        <li><a href="homepage.html">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="tipsandtricks.html">Tips and Tricks</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="getintouch.html">Get in Touch</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">Main
    <h1>Tips-and-Tricks</h1>

    <h2>Keyboard Shortcuts</h2>

    <h2>Cut, Copy, Paste shortcuts</h2>

    <p>The keyboard is not used as often as it could or should be. Sure it is used for typing documents or searches on the internet and such.
    <br>But do you really know how to use the keyboard to the best of your abilities? This is where I will show you the cut, copy, and paste shortcuts.
    <br>Now these are ways to make using the keyboard simplier instead of just using the mouse. So you yourself as a computer user can possibly be
    <br>more advanced and efficent. Now the keyboard functions are not hard to use. Below I will list the cut, copy, and paste keyboard shortcuts.
    <br>The keyboard shortcuts require you to hold down two different keys at the same time.</p>
    <p>First you will select the text or the image that you would like to cut or copy. When you do that it will look highlighted.</p>
    <p>Second you will press the control key. The control key is shown as <strong>ctrl</strong> on the keyboard next to the shift button.</p>
    <p>Third and finally, while you will continue holding down the <strong>ctrl</strong> key you will press either the x, c or v key for the desired function</p>

    <h2>CUT</h2>

    <p>The cut command or shortcut is used simply to remove texts or images from a screen that you are currently working on.
    <br>The cut shortcut moves the information to a place where it is stored and is readily available unless it is overwritten by the next cut or copy command.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Below you will see the keys that are used to do the cut shortcut function</p>
    <img src="images/keyboardshortcutcut.png" alt="Cut Shortcut Key" />

    <h2>COPY</h2>

    <p>The copy command is used as stated. It copies the text or images from the screen that you have selected and strores it.
    <br>Also until it is overwritten by the next cut or copy command.</p>
    <br>
    <p>In the image below you will see the keys that are used to do the copy shortcut function.</p>
    <img src="images/keyboardshortcutcopy.png" alt="Copy Shortcut Key" />

    <h2>PASTE</h2>

    <p>The paste command is used to place the information whether it be an image or text that you have stored on your
    <br>virtual clipboard in the location that you have placed your cursor mouse.</p>
    <p>Below in the image you will see the third and final funtction shortcut key which is used to do the paste shortcut function</p>
    <img src="images/keyboardshortcutpaste.png" alt="Paste Shortcut Key" />
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer
    <h3>Creative Minds Inc.  Jon Mo<h3>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML or link, and do you know your "CSS code homepage" and "CSS code every other page" are identical?

Comment: I added in the html.  Yes I know that the pages are the same.  So what is the issue with the code as to why the homepage main section box is longer than the text?

Comment: For what it's worth I tried it out and can't find the issue you describe. Do you mean the main div with the white background is too long on your homepage? It looks the correct size to me.

Comment: Yes because. i wanted the background to extend with the text like the others do.  do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, still don't see the problem. The background (white background on `<div id="main">`) *is* extending with the text. Noting that you have much less text (just one H2 and H3) on your homepage compared to the other page.

Comment: `float: center` is an invalid property.

Comment: I just tried something random and put in alot of line breaks with random text.  And it went past the white background.  I do not know what is wrong.  Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if you're talking about the h3 element default margin that gets added, but if that's the case just add an id to the h3 element and the following rule to the css. The

```
<h3 id="remove-default-margin">Design, Develop, Dream</h3>

<style>
    #remove-default-margin{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u5Kf/)